# How to print a microsoft word document from Java web server?

Tags: java

Are there any open source or commercial API available to print word document from Java application?

Comment: Print from a server?  What does this mean, render to HTML?

Comment: Send to printer from Tomcat server.

Comment: Java web server?  Do you mean a servlet?  Or just a Java desktop app?  Please add more information to your question.

Comment: You want to print to a printer that is attached to the same computer that is running Tomcat?  Or you want a client to print a Word document that your Tomcat server sends to them?  If the latter, why not just serve the Word document directly?

Comment: I want to print to a printer that is attached to the same computer that is running Tomcat.

Comment: forgot to answer other question: it is a servlet application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to print a *.doc or *.docx file, you need an application that renders the document with max fidelity, and only Microsoft Word can do that. While there are APIs that let you open the document and extract content, it does not seem this is helpful to you.

This leaves you with only one option - COM automation. There are commercial products for this, there may be free ones too. [Here is an example](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/other_examples/Word_from_Java.htm).

A warning: Office automation on a Web server has traditionally been a cumbersome thing to do. It is resource-intensive and unstable. I would try to design around it (i.e. see if you can change the document format, or they way it is created, or the business process).

Comment: Agree with your comments. But unfortunately not many solution in the world as simple as Microsoft Word. I am even ready buy a commercial reliable API to retain the word document reporting power in our system.

Comment: marking this answer as right one, since there no other better way to do.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be able to do it from the command line. Look here: http://fvue.nl/wiki/ClassExec#Printing

You might also want to look at this [How can I print Office documents from .NET in a uniform manner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559481/uniform-way-to-print-office-documents-programatically)

yet another possibility is to use OpenOffice to print from the command line.

```
"C:\Program Files\OpenOffice.org 2.3\program\soffice.exe" -pt "Lexmark T640 (MS)" "c:\word_documents\AAA_TEST_DMHM_53317_696198.doc"
```